# I can't (vote to) close a question I voted to close before but then retracted?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, retracted-close-votes

For example...

I closed a vote for 'too broad'.
But then I realized I wanted to close it as a specific duplicate of another question instead.
So I retracted my close vote.  That worked.
But I can't now vote to close as duplicate and the title says I already voted to close.

Maybe this is intentional but it doesn't feel that way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is by design. When you retract your close vote there is a statement that you will not be able to vote again on that particular question.

[image: Chrome for Mac popup]

As @AnnaLear has stated in the comments below, "the reasoning behind this is that we want to prevent people from abusing close votes. One possible scenario is repeatedly voting to close to trigger closure reviews. Keeping everyone to just one close vote per question levels the playing field and helps prevent close/reopen wars"

Comment: @Bart yea, that's right. And on Chrome for Mac it is a popup. Just uploaded pic of the popup.

Comment: Sorry, just removed my comment when I saw your picture. :)

Comment: The reasoning behind this is that we want to prevent people from abusing close votes. One possible scenario is repeatedly voting to close to trigger closure reviews. Keeping everyone to just one close vote per question levels the playing field and helps prevent close/reopen wars.

Comment: @AnnaLear I had the feeling that it was to prevent "playing" with a question by keeping the question in a closure "limbo" of sorts. I hadn't thought of the abuse of triggering the closure reviews. I will add that to my answer to make it more complete. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, you mean the Chrome team didn't uglify pop-up dialogs on the Mac version like they just did on the latest Windows version? Shoot. Those Mac people get all the good stuff. Too bad I'm a Windows programmer.