# How to change close vote

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I voted to close a question as unclear but then I realized that the question was too broad instead.

Is there a way to change my close reason because if I retract the close vote, I won't be able to vote to close again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way for you to change your vote.

(Unless you happen to be a mod, as mods can vote to close as many times as they want.)

Comment: Then i guess I'll make this a feature request

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi It'd be a duplicate.  [A recent one at that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200391/allow-another-close-vote-after-retraction)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that meta posts turned into feature requests. neat.

Comment: @Servy I've encountered this before. The edit wasn't rolled back. Instead my answer that 5 upvotes was deleted by a moderator???

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi If the question wasn't appropriate before, and would have been deleted without the edit, then I can see that being appropriate.