# Close vote retraction confirmation prompt incorrectly says re-voting is never allowed

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, vote-to-close, retracted-close-votes

There is an existing feature-request, *[Allow another close vote after retraction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200391/allow-another-close-vote-after-retraction)*, that is marked as completed. Per that request, it is now possible to vote to close a question again after retracting a previous close vote.

However, when I retracted close vote, I still get a warning that voting to close again will not be allowed.

<strike>If removing retract restriction was indeed completed,  the warning should be removed from retract close message (if message is needed  at all?).</strike> 
Update from the answers: the retract restriction has not been removed, but was limited for 14 days (can vote again once it would be allowed had one not retracted). The message implies that re-voting is **never** allowed; it should state that voting again will be allowed after 14 days.

<strike>If</strike> As the allow-another-close-vote-after-retraction has not been fully completed, the feature request *[Allow another close vote after retraction](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200391/allow-another-close-vote-after-retraction)* should be updated and considered for full implementation.

Comment: I just tried and after retracting a close vote, I'm not allowed to vote again. So, the warning is correct, the status-completed is not.

Comment: Testing indicates the *current state* of the system is that you can **never** re-cast a retracted close-vote (CV). For example, as a test, I close-voted [this question](/questions/5212) at 2021-10-06 04:38:15Z and retracted it shortly thereafter. I *still*, nearly 3 months later, can't re-vote to close. I don't know if the system was ever as you describe (able to re-cast retracted close-votes), but it's not that way now. You *can*, however, re-cast an aged-away close-vote 14 days after it ages away (your CV ages away somewhere between 3.5+ to 14.5+ days after you initially cast the CV).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As can been seen in the linked question [revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/200391/revisions), the "status-completed" tag was added by [animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/141525/animuson) in Revision #7 on Oct. 8, 2015 at 20:58. Within that same minute time period, animuson also posted a [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200391/allow-another-close-vote-after-retraction#comment867915_200391) stating

> This is now possible as part of the [close vote aging system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting), though you have to wait at least 14 days after you retract your vote to cast a new one.

I consider the current close vote message, i.e.,

[image: Warning message when you try to retract the close vote that you cannot vote again]

to be misleading. I suggest it should also state you can vote again after 14 days.

**Update:** As [Makyen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/271271/makyen)'s [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356942/close-vote-retraction-confirmation-prompt-incorrectly-says-re-voting-is-never-al/356944#comment1248055_356944) states, testing indicates that what animuson wrote is, at least now, incorrect, i.e., currently "you can **never** re-cast your close-vote after retracting it". I'm awaiting what animuson responds with to Makyen's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200391/allow-another-close-vote-after-retraction#comment1248062_200391) asking about this issue.

**Update #2:** Note [Catija](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija) has added an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376337/562482) here which explains what is going on, e.g., one can't recast a close vote after retraction.

Comment: I agree, that the message should be changed to reflect the current functionality.  However I disagree that close votes expire after 14 days can be considered as completion of that request.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim If you disagree with that, file a new feature request asking that it be changed.

Comment: Testing indicates that you can **never** re-cast your close-vote after retracting it. This answer is perpetuating inaccurate information.

Comment: @Makyen Thank you for this information. I was waiting for Animuson to respond to your other comment before doing anything else. However, although Animuson has been active on this site, he may be waiting for someone else, possibly not available due to the holiday season, so it may still be at least a few more days before he replies to you. As such, I've added an update to my answer for now and will update it appropriately once Animuson responds.

Answer (score 5):

I've [written an answer to the linked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376336/284336) explaining the reality of retracting close votes and I've also removed the status tag from the question and deleted the comments that indicate it's completed.

In summary, you can *only* recast a close vote when the vote ages away. You can not recast a close vote when you retract the vote. As such, the warning is correct and does not need to be changed.

Apologies for any confusion this error has caused.